# How to deal with brother-in-law drinking and smoking way too much?

Tags: how-to-help, depression

## Story

I'm 25 years old - my GF is 24 -, her brother is 20.

He is a very kind and easy-going person, we both have sympathy and consideration for each other.
However I noticed that during family meeting at their parent's home he is most of the time *away* : while at table with us he stays quiet, he will be leaving table early, he might get angry quite easily whereas there is no apparent reason for me, he wakes up very very late, etc.

He will not let you think that he is feeling poorly, he is actually pretty good at faking and let you think he is alright.

At the moment, my GF and him are both in an internship in Canada for several months, sharing a big room. She reported to me that he is drinking alcohol - not only during parties, but even ***on his own***  while watching series alone. He drinks vodka, whiskey, beer, anything he can find.
She also reported that he is smoking a lot of weed.

You need to understand that he is not earning any salary, he is not working during holidays to make money, the only money income he has is parents. He looks a bit immature on few points, such as *value* : he is constantly breaking his phone (parents pay to repair or replace it, it doesn't help him to understand how hard money is earned), he is buying a lot of alcohol and weed with his parents' income, etc.
Facts show a selfish behavior. He also needs a lot of attention, he likes hug with its parents.

## Trigger

While we don't know what factors might have trigger this passive self-destroy behavior, I know he had a difficult love-story that ended in breaking (*his gf left him for someone else*). I assume it plays a role, but I can't imagine this is the only reason.

## Question

At the moment, we're looking carefully at him so it does not get worse.
However, we do not have any clue of what we should do to truely help him.
What shall we do to help him so he can realize that his behavior is not sustainable for himself ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, a great way I've found to deal with myself or friends of mine suffering at times is to take them out, mostly during the day and do some activities together that don't involve (or at least limit) the behavior you want to avoid. Outdoorsy stuff, chill in the park, this kind of stuff. At this it would important to stress the fact that any true change will be slow and this whole thing will be a process. Some effort and resilience will have to be exercised to make sure things don't go South. So, indeed, if you think that he doesn't need any real help, spending the most amount of time you can with him outside his area of comfort (maybe also outside yours, so he doesn't feel controlled) would be the best.